# Scanning user-uploaded files for malware in a python-based web framework

Tags: python, django, web2py, python-module, virus-scanning

I'd like to ask web2py and django users which tools/modules they use to scan user-uploaded files for malicious software, viruses, etc. Can you offer any recommendations, based on your personal experience? Thank you.

Comment: I believe a lot of this has to do with filetypes. Restricting executable filetypes usually solves this for me - or on an even broader level - If it's an image upload field, simply restricting uploads to only image filetypes. Also OS level folder structure permissions are important in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks, HL. However, I want to allow for a variety of file types (although no executables), and isn't it the case that binary files of all sorts have the potential to contain embedded malware?

Answer (score 2):

After further thought, and going back to different projects - here is my findings for you:

You can load  Clamscan on your production server. It's UNIX-based, free, and is regularly updated. http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/

Clam scan is console based - so you can just use python to make the needed command line call whenever a user uploads a file. Quick and not resource intensive because you are just scanning one file - not your entire server.

Comment: Thanks, HL. I'll consider it, but would still be glad to hear more options before settling on a solution. I've seen this variant of clamav: http://xael.org/norman/python/pyclamav/ , but it appears development on it stopped ages ago, so not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Sure, makes sense to me. You probably don't have to look for a python-specific solution if you are installing an antivirus system on the server's OS. Since you can run any command you need from your python framework

Answer (score 2):

I'm just at the same decision point myself. Found this
[django-antivirus](https://code.google.com/p/django-antivirus/) project which looks like it was last updated in 2009?

This [python clamd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clamd/1.0.2) project looks much more up-to-date (Aug. 2014). It can scan a stream, which might be the way I'll go for scanning files as they are uploaded.